# How to draw a map in R with varing detail of the countries displayed?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code that plots the map of Brazil, however I need the map to show the states limits, how do I do this?

```
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") class(world)

sites <- data.frame(Longitude = c(-55.8683, -42.9999, -39.0676, -35.1046, -39.7717, -42.4000, -48.9946, -41.0526, -53.0000), Latitude = c(-1.7670, -5.0951, -13.3724, -8.7500, -18.7747, -5.0892, -12.4332, -21.6488, 4.0040))

row.names(sites) <- c("1 Oriximiná-PA", "2-7 Timon-MA", "3 Valença-BA", "4 Tamandaré-PE", "5 Guriri-ES", "6 Teresina-PI", "8-9 Brasil", "10 São João da Bara-RJ", "11 Guiana Francesa") sites

sites$Cidades <- c("Oriximiná - PA", "Timon - MA", "Valença - BA", "Tamandaré - PE", "Guriri - ES", "Teresina - PI", "Brasil - BR", "São João da Bara - RJ", "Guiana Francesa - GF") sites

ggplot(data = world) + geom_sf() + geom_point(data = sites, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, shape= Cidades), size = 3) + scale_shape_manual("Cidades", values = c(17, 15, 13, 7, 4, 0, 6, 19, 1)) + coord_sf(xlim = c(-60, -29), ylim = c(-23, 6), expand = FALSE) + theme(text = element_text(size=10), plot.title = element_text(size=12, hjust=0.5), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle=0, hjust=1), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, angle=0, vjust=1), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9, angle=0), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 9, angle=90))
```

Comment: You need the state border as a polygon to use it with `geom_sf`

Comment: I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
#> Google's Terms of Service: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/.
#> Please cite ggmap if you use it! See citation("ggmap") for details.
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'raster'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     select
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract

sites <- data.frame(
  Longitude = c(-55.8683, -42.9999, -39.0676, -35.1046, -39.7717, -42.4000, -48.9946, -41.0526, -53.0000),
  Latitude = c(-1.7670, -5.0951, -13.3724, -8.7500, -18.7747, -5.0892, -12.4332, -21.6488, 4.0040)
)
sites
#>   Longitude Latitude
#> 1  -55.8683  -1.7670
#> 2  -42.9999  -5.0951
#> 3  -39.0676 -13.3724
#> 4  -35.1046  -8.7500
#> 5  -39.7717 -18.7747
#> 6  -42.4000  -5.0892
#> 7  -48.9946 -12.4332
#> 8  -41.0526 -21.6488
#> 9  -53.0000   4.0040

# Coarse map of neighbor countries (level 0)
other_countries <-
  c("Peru", "Bolivia", "French Guiana", "Suriname", "Guyana",
    "Venezuela", "Colombia", "Ecuador", "Peru", "Bolivia",
    "Paraguay", "Uruguay", "Argentina"
    ) %>%
  map(~ getData(country = .x, level = 0)) %>%
  reduce(rbind)

# Detailed map of Brazil (level 1)
getData(country = "Brazil", level = 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
  geom_polygon(
    mapping = aes(group = group),
    color = "black",
    fill = "grey"
  ) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = other_countries,
    mapping = aes(group = group),
    colour = "black", fill = "transparent"
  ) +
  geom_point(data = sites, mapping = aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), color = "red") +
  coord_fixed()
#> Regions defined for each Polygons
#> Regions defined for each Polygons
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for helping, you helped me a lot. But how do I add the other countries in Latin America? As you can see there is a point located in French Guiana

Comment: @ThiagoSoares I revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. 
I have just one last question, I added more countries to make the map more "beautiful". How do I change the level of these other countries? I would like to put them at level 0. Afterwards, if possible, give me your name, so I can put it in the acknowledgments at the end of the article.

Comment: @ThiagoSoares I revised my answer. Thanks for the acknowledgement :) You can find my name in my Stack overflow profile description.